# Adding tooltips to circle gauge pointers when using Syncfusion

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, syncfusion

I've read the documentation of Syncfusion and I cannot seem to find a way to add a tool tip the pointers of the Syncfusion Circle gauge. Because the gauge uses a canvas to draw and the syncfusion library is pretty intense I haven't tried much beyond reading and a little experimenting with what is there, I just don't want to burn too many hours chasing shadows. Currently when building the gauge I'm throwing something out like below. WE already implement tool tips, but getting them associated with the pointers would be choice. I'm not sure what else I can provide at this moment to provide more clarity.

```
.Scales(sc =>
    {
        sc.StartAngle(180)
        .SweepAngle(180)
        .ShowRanges(true)
        .ShowLabels(false)
        .ShowPointers(showpointer)
        .Radius(radius)
        .Minimum(Model.Scaling.Min)
        .Maximum(Model.Scaling.Max)
        .ShowScaleBar(false)
        .MajorIntervalValue(majorIntervalValue)
        .Ticks(tick =>
        {
            tick.Color("#FFFFFF").Height(0).Width(0).Add();
            tick.Color("#FFFFFF").Height(0).Width(0).Add();
        })
        .CustomLabels(cl =>
        {
            cl.Value(String.Format(gaugeFormatString, gaugeValue))
            .Color("black")
            .Font(f => f.Size("40px")
                        .FontFamily("Arial, Sans-Serif")
                        .FontStyle("bold")
            )
            .Position(p => p.X(xLabelPosition).Y(yLabelPosition)).Add();
            //.Position(p => p.X(xLabelPosition)).Add();


            //.PositionBuilder()
        })
        .Ranges(ran =>
        {
            if (Model.Thresholds != null)
            {
                if (thresholdDirection)
                {
                    if (gaugeValue <= (threshold * 100))
                    {
                        ran.Size(gaugethickness).StartValue(0).EndValue(gaugeValue).BackgroundColor("#3AB54B").Border(bor => bor.Color("#3Ab54B")).Add();
                        ran.Size(gaugethickness).StartValue(gaugeValue).EndValue(100).BackgroundColor("#B0D2C8").Border(bor => bor.Color("#B0D2C8")).Add();
                    }
                    else if (gaugeValue < (secondaryThreshold * 100))
                    {
                        ran.Size(gaugethickness).StartValue(0).EndValue(gaugeValue).BackgroundColor("#f5e132").Border(bor => bor.Color("#f5e132")).Add();
                        ran.Size(gaugethickness).StartValue(gaugeValue).EndValue(100).BackgroundColor("#f1ecbc").Border(bor => bor.Color("#f1ecbc")).Add();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        ran.Size(gaugethickness).StartValue(0).EndValue(gaugeValue).BackgroundColor("#e60000").Border(bor => bor.Color("#e60000")).Add();
                        ran.Size(gaugethickness).StartValue(gaugeValue).EndValue(100).BackgroundColor("#ff6666").Border(bor => bor.Color("#ff6666")).Add();
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    if (gaugeValue >= (threshold * 100) && threshold > 0)
                    {
                        ran.Size(gaugethickness).StartValue(0).EndValue(gaugeValue).BackgroundColor("#3AB54B").Border(bor => bor.Color("#3Ab54B")).Add();
                        ran.Size(gaugethickness).StartValue(gaugeValue).EndValue(100).BackgroundColor("#B0D2C8").Border(bor => bor.Color("#B0D2C8")).Add();
                    }
                    else if (gaugeValue > (secondaryThreshold * 100) && secondaryThreshold > 0)
                    {
                        ran.Size(gaugethickness).StartValue(0).EndValue(gaugeValue).BackgroundColor("#f5e132").Border(bor => bor.Color("#f5e132")).Add();
                        ran.Size(gaugethickness).StartValue(gaugeValue).EndValue(100).BackgroundColor("#f1ecbc").Border(bor => bor.Color("#f1ecbc")).Add();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        ran.Size(gaugethickness).StartValue(0).EndValue(gaugeValue).BackgroundColor("#e60000").Border(bor => bor.Color("#e60000")).Add();
                        ran.Size(gaugethickness).StartValue(gaugeValue).EndValue(100).BackgroundColor("#ff6666").Border(bor => bor.Color("#ff6666")).Add();
                    }
                }

            }
            else
            {
                ran.Size(gaugethickness).StartValue(0).EndValue(gaugeValue).BackgroundColor("#428bca").Border(bor => bor.Color("#428bca")).Add();
                ran.Size(gaugethickness).StartValue(gaugeValue).EndValue(100).BackgroundColor("#a6bfd5").Border(bor => bor.Color("#a6bfd5")).Add();
            }

        })
        .Pointers(po =>
        {

            if (threshold > 0)
            {
                po.BackgroundColor("#3AB54B")
                        .Border(bor => bor.Color("#3AB54B").Width(0))
                        .Type(PointerType.Marker)
                        .MarkerType(MarkerType.Rectangle)
                        .Length(5)

                        //.BackgroundColor(colorthresholdone)
                        .Width(gaugethickness + 10)
                        .Value(threshold * 100)
                        .DistanceFromScale(5)
                        .PointerValueText(pov => pov.ShowValue(false).Distance(-5)
                            .Opacity(1)
                            .autoAngle(false)
                            .Angle(0)
                            .Font(fo => fo.Size("15px")
                            .FontFamily("Arial, Sans-Serif")
                            .FontStyle("Normal")
                         )
                            )
                            .Add();
            }
            if (secondaryThreshold > 0)
            {
                po.BackgroundColor("#f5e132")
                    .Border(bor => bor.Color("#f5e132").Width(0))
                    .Type(PointerType.Marker)
                    .MarkerType(MarkerType.Rectangle)
                    .Length(5)
                    //.BackgroundColor(colorthreshholdtwo)
                    .Width(gaugethickness + 10)
                    .Value(secondaryThreshold * 100)
                    .DistanceFromScale(5)
                    .PointerValueText(pov => pov.ShowValue(false).Distance(-5)
                        .Opacity(1)
                        .autoAngle(false)
                        .Angle(0)
                        .Font(fo => fo.Size("15px")
                        .FontFamily("Arial, Sans-Serif")
                        .FontStyle("Normal")
                     )
                    )
                    .Add();
            }
        })
        .Add();
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the inconvenience.

As of now, we have provided tooltip support for labels and didn’t provide support for pointers in circular gauge, so we logged feature request for your requirement and this will be available in any of our upcoming Essential Studio release. For more information regarding this, kindly create a support incident under your Syncfusion account for proper follow up.

Thanks,
Dharani.